# ASP.NET identity doesnt work with web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I tried to add ASP.NET Identity to my Web API 2 project. The rest service works fine but whenever I try to register (at http://localhost:3216/Account/Register)  this happens:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

there it happens:

```
 var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

If you need further information about the code feel free to ask but at the moment I dont know what code snippets could help you.

Best regards!

Comment: Have you opened the firewall ports between the web server and the database server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you reference the context you used gor the Rest Service?

In the Microsoft example they created another for testing purposes. Just use the same context as for your Rest Service and I should work fine.

Comment: worked for me! thanks I was a bit confused about this...  I am new in asp.net :)